# Java 2D - Cannot get code to work for generating points for a line with a start point and Angle

Tags: mathematics, graphics-programming

I am developing a Java 2D video game.  I am trying to write code to generate points for a line (actually a projectile path), at a specified angle, from a given start point.  There seems to be something wrong with my Math.  The points are to be used for moving a projectile from the top of the screen, towards the target (a submarine) which sits at the bottom.

I am suspicuous issue has to do with fact the origin of Java 2D coordinate system is 0,0 at top of the screen, not at bottom left for cartesian coordinate system.  Note: I am not a Math person.  So please excuse me if I am getting the terms wrong.

Here is what I am doing:

xloc, yloc - the initial location of the projectile I want to move towards the sub location

```
// Get slope of the line
float m= ((float)((int) yloc - subYcoord))/((int) xloc - subXcoord);

double radians= Math.atan(m);

double ycoord= yloc;
double xcoord= xloc;

int speed= 1;

// This is how I am attempting to generate the points for the path for the projectile to take

while (true) {

    xcoord += speed * Math.cos (radians);
    ycoord -= speed * Math.sin (radians);

    if (((int) ycoord)>= gunBaseYcoord) {

        break;
    }

    // WayPoints is my list of points to move the Projectile towards the sub at    bottom of the screen

    Point aPoint= new Point((int) xcoord, (int) ycoord);
    wayPoints.add(aPoint);
}
```

This does not seem to work for angles of 245 degrees.

As an example, if x,y are: 660, 35 (this would be my start point for the projectile), and subXcoord, subYcoord are: 169, 500

I get a slope of: -.947 (should be like: 245 degrees)

The radian is: -.758

I get degrees of: -43 (now this doesn't look right)

Appreciate any help with this!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the vector based method Bruno Vieira Costa mentioned in the edit, in a bit more detail:

Given `projectileX` & `projectileY`, `targetX` & `targetY`, we can think of each of these as a vector (arrow) pointing from the origin of our space `(0, 0)` to the respective objects.

By subtracting the projectile position from the target position, we get a vector (arrow) pointing from the projectile to the target:

```
differenceX = targetX - projectileX
differenceY = targetY - projectileY
```

We can "normalize" this vector to a length of one (a so-called "unit vector") to express just the direction of travel ([using Pythagorean Theorem](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/75543/39518)):

```
distance = sqrt(differenceX * differenceX + differenceY * differenceY)
directionX = differenceX/distance
directionY = differenceY/distance
```

Then we can move at a given `speed` along this direction like so:

```
currentX += speed * directionX
currentY += speed * directionY
```

We can use the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) to figure out whether two vectors are pointing in similar directions (>0), opposing directions (<0), or perpendicular (0), and use this to detect when we've passed our target

```
differenceX = targetX - currentX
differenceY = targetY - currentY

dot = differenceX * directionX + differenceY * directionY

if(dot <= 0)
   // The target is now behind us, we passed it! Stop drawing our line.
```

You can see there's a lot of redundancy in the lines above, repeating the same code for both X and Y. Generally a vector math library will let you perform addition/subtraction and various multiplication operations on vectors as a whole, so don't have a lot of separate x & y (and in 3D, z or even w) variables to manage yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping to fill in the blanks!  You really saved the day!  Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that tan function is not injective in [-pi .. pi] interval.
[image]

You should use atan2 instead. This function need 2 parameters: deltay and deltax
[image]

**edit:**

Instead of using atan, you can only get the difference vector: (deltaX,deltaY) and normalize it and multiply by the speed you need.

Comment: Viera Costa - could you explain what I would need to do to normalize it?  I read that the atan2() function calculates with respect to the x-axis (I assume 0,0?).  I need it to calculate with respect to location of the submarine.  How do I adjust the return value of atan2() to account for this? Thanks!

Comment: Viera Costa - I tried using the difference vector: double radians= Math.atan2(xloc - gunBaseXcoord, yloc - gunBaseYcoord);

Comment: Viera Costa- But the difference vector seems at times to return the wrong angle.

Comment: Ok, so don't use tan, and instead use vectors?  Can you note a good resource to understand Vectors Math for Java?  Have a learning curve here!  Thanks!

Comment: It depends of your learning style, I'm visual, so I like videos like khan academy's [linear algebra course](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces).

The good part is that you don't need any Java specific material for this subject, any math book can help you